# Export standalone offline html plot of matplotlib figures using mpld3

Tags: javascript, html, matplotlib, d3.js, mpld3

I am trying to export matplotlib figures using mpld3 to standalone html files.
This works :

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax = ax.plot(np.arange(10))

with open("graph.html", "w") as fileobj:
    mpld3.save_html(plt.gcf(), fileobj)
```

the export does occur, and the graph shows as expected when I open the html file in a browser with an internet connection. Interstingly, it also shows as expected without internet connection. How is this possible, since I expect the html tries to get the js components (d3 and mpld3) from online cdn ?

Secondly, I downloaded the [mpld3 repo](https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3) and unziped the content, in order to have a local copy of the js d3 and mpld3 [here](https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3/tree/master/mpld3/js). So I used the following to try and export a html file for offline use, using :

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax = ax.plot(np.arange(10))

with open("graph.html", "w") as fileobj:
    mpld3.save_html(plt.gcf(), fileobj,
                    d3_url=r"path\to\mpld3-master\mpld3\js\d3.v5.min.js",
                    mpld3_url=r"path\to\mpld3-master\mpld3\js\mpld3.v0.5.1.min.js",
                    )
```

according to the doc [here](http://mpld3.github.io/modules/API.html#mpld3.fig_to_html) and [here](http://mpld3.github.io/modules/API.html#mpld3.save_html). But when doing this, the html appears blank in the browser. Here the source code :

```html
<style>

</style>

<div id="fig_el158242311667823952363636180"></div>
<script>
function mpld3_load_lib(url, callback){
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = url;
  s.async = true;
  s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = callback;
  s.onerror = function(){console.warn("failed to load library " + url);};
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
}

if(typeof(mpld3) !== "undefined" && mpld3._mpld3IsLoaded){
   // already loaded: just create the figure
   !function(mpld3){
       
       mpld3.draw_figure("fig_el158242311667823952363636180", {"width": 1280.0, "height": 960.0, "axes": [{"bbox": [0.125, 0.10999999999999999, 0.775, 0.77], "xlim": [-0.45, 9.45], "ylim": [-0.45, 9.45], "xdomain": [-0.45, 9.45], "ydomain": [-0.45, 9.45], "xscale": "linear", "yscale": "linear", "axes": [{"position": "bottom", "nticks": 7, "tickvalues": null, "tickformat_formatter": "", "tickformat": null, "scale": "linear", "fontsize": 10.0, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true}, {"position": "left", "nticks": 7, "tickvalues": null, "tickformat_formatter": "", "tickformat": null, "scale": "linear", "fontsize": 10.0, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true}], "axesbg": "#FFFFFF", "axesbgalpha": null, "zoomable": true, "id": "el158242311667809200", "lines": [{"data": "data01", "xindex": 0, "yindex": 1, "coordinates": "data", "id": "el158242311667979264", "color": "#1F77B4", "linewidth": 1.5, "dasharray": "none", "alpha": 1, "zorder": 2, "drawstyle": "default"}], "paths": [], "markers": [], "texts": [], "collections": [], "images": [], "sharex": [], "sharey": []}], "data": {"data01": [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [5.0, 5.0], [6.0, 6.0], [7.0, 7.0], [8.0, 8.0], [9.0, 9.0]]}, "id": "el158242311667823952", "plugins": [{"type": "reset"}, {"type": "zoom", "button": true, "enabled": false}, {"type": "boxzoom", "button": true, "enabled": false}]});
   }(mpld3);
}else if(typeof define === "function" && define.amd){
   // require.js is available: use it to load d3/mpld3
   require.config({paths: {d3: "path\to\mpld3-master\mpld3\js\d3.v5.min"}});
   require(["d3"], function(d3){
      window.d3 = d3;
      mpld3_load_lib("path\to\mpld3-master\mpld3\js\mpld3.v0.5.1.min.js", function(){
         
         mpld3.draw_figure("fig_el158242311667823952363636180", {"width": 1280.0, "height": 960.0, "axes": [{"bbox": [0.125, 0.10999999999999999, 0.775, 0.77], "xlim": [-0.45, 9.45], "ylim": [-0.45, 9.45], "xdomain": [-0.45, 9.45], "ydomain": [-0.45, 9.45], "xscale": "linear", "yscale": "linear", "axes": [{"position": "bottom", "nticks": 7, "tickvalues": null, "tickformat_formatter": "", "tickformat": null, "scale": "linear", "fontsize": 10.0, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true}, {"position": "left", "nticks": 7, "tickvalues": null, "tickformat_formatter": "", "tickformat": null, "scale": "linear", "fontsize": 10.0, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true}], "axesbg": "#FFFFFF", "axesbgalpha": null, "zoomable": true, "id": "el158242311667809200", "lines": [{"data": "data01", "xindex": 0, "yindex": 1, "coordinates": "data", "id": "el158242311667979264", "color": "#1F77B4", "linewidth": 1.5, "dasharray": "none", "alpha": 1, "zorder": 2, "drawstyle": "default"}], "paths": [], "markers": [], "texts": [], "collections": [], "images": [], "sharex": [], "sharey": []}], "data": {"data01": [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [5.0, 5.0], [6.0, 6.0], [7.0, 7.0], [8.0, 8.0], [9.0, 9.0]]}, "id": "el158242311667823952", "plugins": [{"type": "reset"}, {"type": "zoom", "button": true, "enabled": false}, {"type": "boxzoom", "button": true, "enabled": false}]});
      });
    });
}else{
    // require.js not available: dynamically load d3 & mpld3
    mpld3_load_lib("path\to\mpld3-master\mpld3\js\d3.v5.min.js", function(){
         mpld3_load_lib("path\to\mpld3-master\mpld3\js\mpld3.v0.5.1.min.js", function(){
                 
                 mpld3.draw_figure("fig_el158242311667823952363636180", {"width": 1280.0, "height": 960.0, "axes": [{"bbox": [0.125, 0.10999999999999999, 0.775, 0.77], "xlim": [-0.45, 9.45], "ylim": [-0.45, 9.45], "xdomain": [-0.45, 9.45], "ydomain": [-0.45, 9.45], "xscale": "linear", "yscale": "linear", "axes": [{"position": "bottom", "nticks": 7, "tickvalues": null, "tickformat_formatter": "", "tickformat": null, "scale": "linear", "fontsize": 10.0, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true}, {"position": "left", "nticks": 7, "tickvalues": null, "tickformat_formatter": "", "tickformat": null, "scale": "linear", "fontsize": 10.0, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true}], "axesbg": "#FFFFFF", "axesbgalpha": null, "zoomable": true, "id": "el158242311667809200", "lines": [{"data": "data01", "xindex": 0, "yindex": 1, "coordinates": "data", "id": "el158242311667979264", "color": "#1F77B4", "linewidth": 1.5, "dasharray": "none", "alpha": 1, "zorder": 2, "drawstyle": "default"}], "paths": [], "markers": [], "texts": [], "collections": [], "images": [], "sharex": [], "sharey": []}], "data": {"data01": [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [5.0, 5.0], [6.0, 6.0], [7.0, 7.0], [8.0, 8.0], [9.0, 9.0]]}, "id": "el158242311667823952", "plugins": [{"type": "reset"}, {"type": "zoom", "button": true, "enabled": false}, {"type": "boxzoom", "button": true, "enabled": false}]});
            })
         });
}
</script>
```

So my problem comes down to 2 questions :

- how come the first snippet exports a html page that renders without internet connection ?
- why does using d3_url and mpld3_url breaks the html render ?

python : 3.8
matplotlib : 3.2.1
mpldd3 version : 0.5.1

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out my main problem, concerning the use of d3_url and mpld3_url : using [this link](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/51c41b358c1cccc26d00d741), and comparing the source code of the html up above with one generated on a mac, this now works fine :

```py
# note the "file:// prefix and the forward slashes
with open("graph.html", "w") as fileobj:
    mpld3.save_html(plt.gcf(), fileobj,
                    d3_url="file://C:/.../mpld3-master/mpld3/js/d3.v5.min.js",
                    mpld3_url="file://C:/.../mpld3-master/mpld3/js/mpld3.v0.5.1.min.js",
                    )
```

The problem was that the url must be a simple string that stores javascript path, not a python path. Hence the prefix "file://" and the forward slashes in the paths.